# How can I adjust the timeout period in Freeradius Proxy?

Tags: freeradius

Firewall > Freeradius > Auth server

Freeradius is configured to proxy requests.
If it does not get response in 14 seconds from auth server then it times out and sends login failure back to the firewall.
I can't seem to find where to adjust this 14 second to timeout.

Can anyone point me to right location?

```
Log snippet from freeradius -X

Proxying request to home server 192.168.1.10 port 1812 timeout 14.000000
Sent Access-Request Id 155 from 0.0.0.0:59777 to 192.168.1.10:1812 length 113
  User-Name = "test@example.com"
  User-Password = "password"
  NAS-Identifier = "RADIUS"
  NAS-IP-Address = 192.168.1.1
  Event-Timestamp = "May 27 2023 20:33:05 EDT"
  Message-Authenticator := 0x00
  Proxy-State = 0x3437
Waking up in 0.3 seconds.
Expecting proxy response no later than 13.667138 seconds from now
Waking up in 13.6 seconds.

No proxy response, giving up on request and marking it done
Marking home server 192.168.1.10 port 1812 as zombie (it has not responded in 14.000000 seconds).
ERROR: Failing proxied request for user "test@example.com", due to lack of any response from home server 192.168.1.10 port 1812
Clearing existing &reply: attributes
Found Post-Proxy-Type Fail-Authentication
server default {
  Post-Proxy-Type sub-section not found.  Ignoring.
  Executing group from file /etc/freeradius/3.0/sites-enabled/default
```